# Return values of checked checkboxes as CSV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I have check-boxes inside like;

```
<form id="testid">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="option 1" />option 1
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="option 2" />option 2
    <br/><br/><a id="test">test</a>
</form>
```

I need the value of checked check-boxes returned when i click some element. Say, I need to alert;

1. `option1,option2` if both boxes are checked,
2. `option1` if only option 1 is checked,
3. alert an empty box if none is selected.

How can I achieve this? **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/H8HNm/)** is the fiddle.

Comment: If it's a CSV do you also need a heading row composed of the element's names, or just the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fiddle which answers your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/H8HNm/1/

The key is this:

```
checked = []
$(".chkbx:checked").each(function () {
       checked.push($(this).val())
});
alert(checked.join(","))
```

This code loops through all selected checkboxes and adds them to an array. Then joins them together to make the final output.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter()` and `.map()`:

```
var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return this.checked;
}).map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```